# Find all double quotes between parenthesis preceded by a specific expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using Notepad++ I want to find all the double quotes in a string starting with `expr(` and ending with the nearest `)`, like

```
expr("hi","",0)
```

so as to replace these with single quotes, as follows

```
expr('hi','',0)
```

This string can be found several times in a longer text like

```
bla="asd" expr("hello","",0) something something expr("bye","",0) something "later" etc
```

I tried several regular expressions to no avail, like

```
(?<=expr\()("*?)(?=\))
```

I need to do this in several files, so thats why I use Notepad++.

Is this possible at all?
Please help.

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!^),?|\bexpr\()\K"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"` -> `'$1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex only matches 0+ double quotes that are immediately preceded with `expr(` and immediately followed with `)`.

I suggest using the following regex:

```
(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|\bexpr\()\s*\K"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"
```

and replace with `'$1'`.

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|\bexpr\()` - whole word `expr(` (`\bexpr\(`) or the end of the previous successful match + a comma enclosed with 0+ whitespaces (`\G(?!^)\s*,\s*`)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - omits the text matched so far
- `"`  - a double quote
- `((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)` - Group 1 capturing the double quoted string literal (0+ chars other than `"` and `\` (with `[^"\\]`) or any escape sequence (`\\.`)
- `"` - a double quote

See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Wiktor, thanks for your explanation. I will try and let you know later!

Comment: Wiktor, I figured out the regex and learned something new :) Very nice! Thanks again.